# How should I decide whether to take over someone else's work tasks?

Tags: colleagues, task-management, helping

My coworker is struggling with a task. I know that if I do it, it will take about 40 hours. I estimate that at the current rate, it will take my coworker at least three times that. So the first argument for stepping in is efficiency.

The second argument is result quality. She got the task "per default", because it is part of a larger project she is responsible for. But the specific skills required for executing the task are mostly from the field I specialize in, and she lacks the knowledge and experience needed for it. My knowledge in her field is limited, but still sufficient for me to complete the task and achieve better results than she could, even though she gives her best.

The third argument for it is simple compassion. Doing it is hard for her, she struggles a lot only to end up with mediocre results, and this demotivates her. It has no benefits for her to go through it, she is not learning a skill she would need elsewhere. I could spare her the trouble, without suffering myself.

But there is also a good reason not to do it. Investing 40 hours in her task will endanger an important deadline I have, while she has no deadline for her task.

When I know I can do a task far better than a colleague, how can I evaluate whether or not to actually step in, or whether to let them struggle?

Comment: Is there anything specific here to software development? I think you have a great question here if you remove a lot of the details!

Comment: Hey Rumi, and welcome back to [workplace.se]. I made a very large edit to your post removing a lot of the details that distract from the core of your problem and to get you better answers. If you think I missed something critical, please feel free to [edit] the question with whatever you think is relevant.

Comment: @jmac I can see why the more general form is interesting for the site. But in this case I think that her lack of skill is a very important factor, not just the efficiency. I think I will edit that part back in.

Comment: @Rumi, ah, good point, feel free to add it in. You don't actually *need* a general form for questions here, it just tends to get you better answers. When there are a lot of technical details, people often focus on the technical part rather than the general issue (how to decide when to take over tasks from a coworker). It is totally up to you how much detail to add, I just like starting from the core and letting you add the relevant details to get good answers. Thanks for the question!

Comment: I'd love to answer something like this question (how can I make sure the right person performs the task), but I can't answer it as asked. The reason I say this is that I think you should raise these concerns with your boss and, yes, you can do this without totally panning your coworker.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship, personally I think the answer is, "If you are not a manager, it isn't your choice at all. Managers decide who should do what task based on criteria X, Y, and Z. If you want to do the task, you should explain to your manager why you are a better fit given the criteria your boss is using". Why do you feel you can't answer it as written?

Comment: Because the question is how to decide (yourself) whether to take over the task. I suppose I should say what I think should be done, but technically that doesn't answer the question asked. That probably hasn't stopped me in the past, but maybe I'm just turning over a new leaf. However, the original question does say "Do you see any alternatives I've missed?" so maybe I could answer that part.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship, I think the answer to "how to decide yourself?" is just "don't do it" because it isn't the job of a coworker to step in and take a task without the blessings of the powers that be. Sometimes the answer to a question doesn't tell them how to do what they want to do, but why not to do what they want to do, and an alternative method of getting the same result. As long as the answer is useful to someone in that situation, I can't see an issue myself, but of course it's all up to you.

Comment: @Rumi, absolutely fantastic edit. Thanks for collaborating on this one -- I can't wait to see the answers!

Comment: @AmyBlankenship I am quite sure my manager will let me have the task if I bring good arguments why I should be the one to do it. The coworker will also support me, and she is technically more influential than my manager. And even if the manager stops me from overtaking the task, there is no problem in asking if I may. But I have to decide whether it is a good idea to ask at all, or to let things stay as they are and live with the bad results of her task (and if they are bad, the usefulness of a product I work on is diminished, which I will hate happen even though I won't be held responsible)

Comment: You are ignoring an additional option: help her learn how to do a better job.  Mentor her.  This way, the next time she has to do similar work, she does it better, you don't get loaded with this task that you might not want/have time to do, and you position yourself as a helpful team player.

Comment: @atk I have been trying to do this, but it didn't go that well. The task requires advanced knowledge in a field she doesn't even know the basics of, and has no affinity for it. It is a bit like trying to teach a tone deaf person to compose a guitar song when they can't even play the guitar. She made progress which is very good when compared to where she started at, but is still too far from being able to do it well.

Comment: Is there anyone else at the company who can do the job?  can you break it down into smaller pieces so she can do the ones she can, and someone else (you, some third person at the company, or a consultant) can do the rest?

Comment: OK, based on your edits I don't think this needs a full-length answer. Since you have an immediate deadline and she has no deadline, I think you should propose that you take over the project when you have delivered what you are working on.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship a detail I was trying to keep out so the question will not become too concrete: the product I have to deliver at the deadline will have low user acceptance if her task is not done by then. Officially, nobody can make that her deadline, so she won't suffer if she doesn't get it done. My boss also will know the reason, so I won't suffer if she doesn't get it done. But it will hurt my professional pride to deliver my product and see it scorned by its users. If you want to know all the grisly details, read the first revision of the question, it was very different.

Comment: @atk nobody else that I know of, certainly not in my department. And it is already broken down in pieces, the 40 hours is for the one part which is hardest for her. It cannot be broken down any more.

Answer (score 4):

You need to find a "middle path" , I would not recommend either extremes ....blatantly stepping in & getting it done or letting her struggle. Both will potentially worsen her confidence.

How is your relationship with your co-worker ? i.e. can you approach her from a  soft mentorship perspective ? will you boss be ok with this ?

Personally I use the yardstick of balancing ,investing time into people's development vs hard short-medium project deadlines.
Can you pair up with her to help her achieve some easy wins & also delegate some of your existing work so that your deadline is met ? 
Since she is not under a deadline pressure,set some goals & targets for her to achieve and then gradually focus her on learning & improving.

There seems to be a leadership vacuum in your team & seems like your are taking that initiative to set that right. 
I would focus on not just doing the job better than her but also making her better.

good luck

Answer (score 2):

Do you have the capacity to do it without impacting your work? If not it needs to be pushed to someone who can help manage that aspect too (PM, managers etc).

If you do have the capacity I'd simply ask your colleague about her work load and let her know that you can have some capacity to help out if she needs any help small or large.

The point is that, lots of times we are afraid to ask for help as it feels demeaning to ourselves. The best thing to do is the let them know you are there to help and rather than doing the work for her you're probably in a good place to help her prioritise her load so that she may be able to delegate tasks to you.

As long as she doesn't feel threatened by you helping her (as opposed to to you stepping in and taking her work) then I think it's likely that you can build up to letting her know the areas where you are strong and could help her ask for help in the future too.